# Using FormatFloat in FastReport VCL 5 scripts

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I am trying to print a currency formatted value to a TfrxMemoView on the report with the following script:

```
procedure txCreditLimitOnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  if <TRAN."CREDITAPPROVED"> = 1 then                                
    txCreditLimit.Text := 'Credit Limit: ' + FormatFloat('%2.2m', <TRAN."CREDITLIMIT">)
  else
    txCreditLimit.Text := '';
end;
```

But all that I get out is %2.2m instead of the actual value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like FR doesn't support that format string

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: But this is the string that is used on the format screen for the TfrxMemoView?  I don't see anywhere in the documentation that tells what type of format strings to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function FormatFloat in FastReport is working like [FormatFloat](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.FormatFloat) in Delphi, so you might use:

```
procedure txCreditLimitOnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  if <TRAN."CREDITAPPROVED"> = 1 then                                
    txCreditLimit.Text := 'Credit Limit: ' + FormatFloat('#,##0.00 €', <TRAN."CREDITLIMIT">)
  else
    txCreditLimit.Text := '';
end;
```

Since FormatFloat does not support system currency another way could be to use a memo bound to your dataset containing the expression like e.g. `Credit Limit: [TRAN."CREDITLIMIT"]` and format this memo in the Object Inspector, with the syntax you mentioned.
You condition for printing would change to:

```
procedure txCreditLimitOnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  txCreditLimit.Visible := <TRAN."CREDITAPPROVED"> = 1;
end
```

[image]

Expressions enclosed in square brackets will be calculated in TextObjects, so for example
`[<DS."a">]   * 2  :=   [<DS."a">  +  <DS."a">]` will lead to an output of: `12.50 € * 2 = 25.00 €`
if the format of the TfrxMemoView is defined as `%2.2m`. In the shown example both terms (included in square brackets) are formatted, the second one is in addition calculated.

Comment: That worked great!  Thanks!  As an aside, what do the <> and [] type bracketing mean specifically?  If I had the text set to "Credit Limit: <TRAN."CREDITLIMIT">" it wouldn't work.  When I set it to "Credit Limit: [<TRAN."CREDITLIMIT">]" it does?  You don't even use the <> in your example above so I'm kind of confused.

Comment: @Caynadian I made an edit on the answer regarding your comment.